# JavaScript code is slow (JQuery). Is there a way to optimize it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am doing is drawing rectangle in a div ("#gd_graphics_grid") with divs acting as pixels. The problem is it's kinda slow. On Chrome it might be ok (a bit slow) but on IE it's a nightmare (I know it's normal, because IE JavaScript engine is slow). I want to know if there's a way to optimize this code (tried to, but didn't succeed) :

here's the html/php that generate the divs:

```
<div id="gd_graphics">
    <p id="gd_loader">Veuillez patienter!</p>
    <div id="gd_graphics_grid">
         <?php for($row = 0; $row < 73; $row++) : ?>
         <div class="gd_grid_row">
             <?php for($block = 0; $block < 130; $block++) : ?>
             <div class="gd_grid_block"><div class="gd_grid_block_wrap"></div></div>
            <?php endfor; ?>
            <div class="gd_hidden"></div>
         </div>
         <?php endfor; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the javascript (only the part that refresh (and that slow my code) :

```
function RefreshDrag()
{
    $(".gd_selected_block").removeClass("gd_selected_block");

    if(startX <= endingX)
    {
        var minX = startX;
        var maxX = endingX;
    }
    else
    {
        var minX = endingX;
        var maxX = startX;
    }

    if(startY <= endingY)
    {
        var minY = startY;
        var maxY = endingY;
    }
    else
    {
        var minY = endingY;
        var maxY = startY;
    }

    var $row = null;
    var $block = null;
    var $left = null;
    var $right = null;
    var $this = null;
    var rowIndex = null;

    $(".gd_grid_row").slice(minY, maxY+1).each(function() {
        $row = $(this);
        rowIndex = $row.index();

        if(rowIndex == minY || rowIndex == maxY)
        {
            $row.children(".gd_grid_block").slice(minX, maxX+1).find(".gd_grid_block_wrap").each(function() {
                $this = $(this);

                $this.addClass("gd_selected_block");
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $left  = $row.children(".gd_grid_block").eq(minX).find(".gd_grid_block_wrap");
            $right = $row.children(".gd_grid_block").eq(maxX).find(".gd_grid_block_wrap");

            $left.addClass("gd_selected_block");

            $right.addClass("gd_selected_block");
        }
    });

}
```

.gd_selected_block is a class that change de background color of the div (to act as a line). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to simulate a drag and drop?  http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

Comment: My sincere suggestion is to find a completely different approach. Using individual DIVs as pixels is like building a birdhouse out of toothpicks.

Comment: You shouldn't do that. If it's a D&D, follow Harvey suggestion to do otherwise. If you more generically want to make fast animations, either use SVG or HTML5 Canvas.

Comment: this should fit more on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/10340/ajax333221

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you doing this, in 2012?

Use some SVG library like [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) or use [HTML canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Canvas) element.

If you want to stick with your style, try to use div borders as line, or an img as line and re-position them, though I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: I tried this approach because I dont need a complexe drawing tools... just need to draw few rectangles to define zones..